# Arch Linux Cinnamon Network manager can not recognize certificate

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, cinnamon

I recently switched to Cinnamon, everything works fine other than the fact that I could not connect to the wifi in my university because of I cannot choose the certificate. Here are images of what is going on.

```
http://postimg.org/image/76xzleqzj/
```

As you can see, all the certificate are inside the folder but Network Manager only recognize one of them and it is not the one I need. I tried to hardcoded it in the /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections file, I would load forever but not able to connect. Then in the network connection GUI, i tried to enter the location of the file. But afterward, I could not save the file because the save button is disabled.

```
http://postimg.org/image/jckcihou9/
```

Other than this issue, everything is working perfectly, I can connect to normal wifi and do whatever I need. It is just the University Wifi Could someone please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by running:

```
trust extract-compat
```

as root.

source:
https://www.archlinux.org/news/ca-certificates-update/

EDIT:

In order to then connect to the eduroam network at my university, I had to go into the file:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/my-network
```

And add the line:

```
system-ca-certs=false
```

to the section with heading:

```
[802-1x]
```